# python check string contains all characters

Tags: python, algorithm, python-3.x, nodes, networkx

I'm reading in a long list of words, and I made a node for every word in the list. Each node has an attribute 'word' for their position in the list.

I am trying to connect a node to the next node if the next node is the previous node, with an addition of just one letter

I also alphabetically ordered each word per character, so that CAT -> ACT

I want to draw an edge from each unique starting word, to all of the possible chains, so I can see all the possible chains in the list.

For example

A -> AN -> TAN -> RANT

However A --x-> T

This is my attempt

```
for i in range(0, G.number_of_nodes()-1):

    if ( ( (len(G.node[i]['word'])+1)  == len(G.node[i+1]['word']) )      and (G.node[i]['word'] in G.node[i+1]['word'])):
        print G.node[i]['word'], G.node[i+1]['word']
```

Gave me this,

```
DGO DGOS
DGOS DGOSS
I IN
ELLMS ELLMSS
AEPRS AEPRSS
INW DINW
DINW DINWY
```

[What the word list and the alphabetical list looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0JJj.png)

Why do I not see IN INW?

Also, AGNRT AGNRST should be on there but I don't understand why, along with a lot of other pairs

Where do you think I went wrong?

Comment: TLDR: I think what i'm asking is: How do I check if String2 contains any combination of the characters in String1?

Comment: Have you looked at `itertools.combinations()`? Seems like a good place to start.

Comment: is the next word always having a character in the beginning or the end  only like BEER -> BEERS and not BEER -> BEESR?

Comment: Is the order of the letters supposed to be the same too?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are only comparing words that appear right next to each other in the list, i.e. words `i` and `i+1`, e.g. `I` and `IN` appear next to each other, as do `WIN` and `WIND`, but `IN` and `WIND` are far apart. It seems you want to compare all possible words, which requires a more sophisticated algorithm. Here's an idea:

1. Make a dictionary where they keys are sorted words and the values are lists of actual words, e.g. `{"ACT": ["CAT", "ACT", "TAC], ...}`. A `collections.defaultdict(list)` will be useful for this.
2. Sort the full input list of words by length. You can use `list.sort(key=len)` assuming you have just a list of words.
3. Iterate through the list sorted by length. For each word, go through every subset of length `n-1`. Something like `for i in range(len(word)): process(word[:i] + word[i+1:])`. You may want to be careful about duplicates here.
4. For each subset, sort the subset and look it up in the dictionary. Make a link from every word in the dictionary's value (a list of actual words) to the bigger word.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be comparing each node with just one other node, so

"IN" directly follows "I" in your wordlist, but "INW" is not directly after "IN"

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a formal languages problem. How do you handle looping nodes?

IN INW is in the list you gave.

AGNRT AGNRST are not in the list, because you started out with a single letter, that letter has to be in the next word for example I -> IN, but IN is not in AGNRT or AGNRST

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 3rd party python library, `python-levenshtein`, to calculate the [Levenshtein Distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) which is the string edit distance. In your case, the only allowed 'edit' is the 'insertion' of the character on the next string/word on your list, so you will also need to verify that the length of the next word is 1 plus the previous word.

Here is the sample code that would achieve our stuff:

```
import Levenshtein as lvst

if len(word2) - len(word1) == 1 and lvst.distance(word1, word2) == 1:
    print(word1, word2)
```

You can install `python-levenshtein` by either `apt-get` (systemwide) or `pip`:

`sudo apt-get install python-levenshtein`

or

`sudo apt-get install python3-levenshtein`

or

`pip install python-levenshtein`